# IF else statement in React to change the color of markers in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

So I have a variable "L", that variable can have a value between 1,2,3,4. That is my levels of how serious a crime was committed. I want to change the color of my markers . I have problems understanding where my logic goes in react. This is my code what i have now , inside icon={} is where the color change can be made .

```
render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <div className="floating-panel">
          <button onClick={this.handleToggle}>HeatMap</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleToggle1}>Markers</button>
        </div>
        <div className="map-container">
          <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={14}
            style={mapStyles}
            scrollwheel={true}
            initialCenter={{
              lat: 32.71573699,
              lng: -117.16108799
            }}
          >
            {this.state.isMarkerVisible
              ? this.props.policeCall.map(({ A, B, M, N, L, O }) => {
                  return (
                    <Marker
                      onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                      icon={{if (L ==1){
    url: " http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
}
else if (L==2) {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"

} else if (L==3) {

    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"
}else{
    url : "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png"
}}}
                      name={A}
                      info={B}
                      priority={L}
                      position={{ lat: M, lng: N }}
                      story={O}
                    />
                  );
                })
              : null}
  </Map>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Mcontainer = GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "",
  libraries: ["visualization"]
})(MapContainer);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  policeCall: state.policeCall.policeCall
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Mcontainer);
```

I want to use this type of logic inside my

```
if (L ==1){
    url: " http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
}
else if (L==2) {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"

} else if (L==3) {

    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"
}else{
    url : "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png"
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I edit my question , inside my <Marker icon= {} , i want to change the color of each marker,  by what value L is . L can be a value of 1,2,3,4 . I want it to change the color of my markers with corresponding url. Not sure how to write if else logic inside jsx . How can i do it ? thank you

Comment: did you understand ?

Answer (score 0):

`if` is used to branch on *statements*, you want to branch on different *expressions*, which is what the ternary operator is for:

```
icon={{
  url: L == 1 ? "http://one" : "http://two",
}}
```

However, you'll find out that this is quite repetitive for more values, for that you can then use a lookup array:

```
icon={{
 url: ["", "http://one", "http://two", "http://three"][L] || "http://default",
}}
```

Comment: the lookup array looks good, but having trouble understanding the logic . what is default ? and the empty "" in the beginning ?

Comment: @eduardo arrays are zero based, so ["zero", "one"][0]` would be `"zero"`, and as you want to take the default for L being 0 it makes sense that it is empty. "http://default" is the one taken if no value is included in the array for that L

Comment: `icon={{
 url: ["", "http://one", "http://two", "http://three"][L] || "http://default",
}} ` where would i be comparing the values of my L to match the my value 1 therefore display "blue" , can you write up one example say if L ==1 then blue using the lookuparray ?

Comment: just asking if you can write one example for one color with the variable the link of the image ill do the rest of them